# How should I ask the IT to enable publishing an apex application on Internet?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-apex

I made an application in apex, (I barely learning first steps), which I use for testing.

I have both the database and apex installed on my work PC, and the company has his own Oracle database providing webpages to Internet, which at this point has no interaction with my database and applications.

I want to test my application working from Internet. At this point I can only access it from my internal network at work.

I need it to be accessible from anywhere on internet.

I believe that I need to ask the IT department to expose the application to Internet, (to make it accessible from out of the local network), but I do not know the terminology that I need to use.

What is exactly what I need to ask to the IT department, and what information I need to provide?

_

I guess that I need to ask:

- To open a firewall to ports 1521, 8080 to that computer, or the
  application URL (http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=###), maybe specifying the programs oracle.exe and tnslsnr.exe
- To start or configure "some service"
- To "expose that computer to Internet"
- Something, I have no clue what.

I guess that I need to provide the mentioned ports, the network name of the (windows) computer , and the URL of the application.

Comment: Why don't you ask your IT department what they need to know; you could explain to them exactly as you did here what you want to accomplish.

Comment: The fact that you're currently listing the URL as being on `localhost` isn't a particularly compelling argument that you can give them the URL of the application....

Comment: @RDFozz Do you expect me to publish here the IP of the PC?

Comment: @bewe - Absolutely not. I'm not sure what the point of including a URL here was. I was concerned that you were unaware that the actual URL for others to get to the site wouldn't be a `localhost` URL, from which I would infer that your best bet might be to go into the meeting as if you knew nothing for certain. If you confidently give the IT team a bunch of information that's not correct, you'll just convince them that no information from you can be trusted - not a great start to the conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the *entirely valid* issues raised in David Spillett's answer - the best way to find out what your IT department would need in order to make your application available outside of your company's network is to ask them.

We don't know anything about you network configuration. We don't know if the machine the application is running on gets its IP address via DHCP (in which case that address would change periodically); what firewall rules are in place, and what all would need to be changed; etc.

When you go to the meeting, you should be prepared with everything you know you may need: at a minimum, I'd cover:

- The machine(s) running the apex application.
- All ports required to communicate with the apex application's web interface.
- Current audience for the application.
- Expected traffic.
- Some information on what the application does, and the types of data the it will hold/collect.

First, in most cases the IT organization is responsible, among other things, for making sure that the company's websites stay up and work for their users, internal and external. If you are running this on your personal workstation (or worse, laptop), then the reliability of the site cannot be guaranteed. For testing purposes, this may be adequate; but, you would want to be able to justify why this needs to be globally available for testing purposes, rather than merely available inside the company network. I'm not saying there isn't a reason - it's just a question any responsible IT person would ask.

Even if the apex application is ready for a rollout to the internet at large, they may need to move it and the database it uses to another server or servers, depending on expected traffic.

The IT organization is probably responsible, to one extent or another, for internet security as well (or, at least, concerned with it). They may ask questions about what you've done to guard against common website attacks (SQL injection, for instance). They may even want to do some testing of their own to ensure they don't find any holes before they make the site available.

Again, your IT team may not be directly responsible for compliance, but they are almost certainly involved and concerned. Rules regarding PCI or HIPAA compliance, for instance, are complicated, and violating them can be extremely costly. Hence, the need for info on what data you'll collect and store.

**TL;DR** While it's good to go in as prepared as possible, don't go in expecting to give them a handful of data and be done. This will probably be just a first meeting, and they'll let you know what more they need.

Answer (score 1):

> I barely learning first steps
>
> but I do not know the terminology that I need to use.
>
> I have no clue what

Under these conditions, you shouldn't.

If you don't yet understand the requirements and therefore the security implications your IT department is, quite rightly, simply not going to let you publish an application to the public network from their resources.

When you *are* ready to publish, assuming it is something relevant and useful to the company, **ask your IT department what their procedure is for such tasks** - it will vary form company to company so the only way to know for sure is to ask them what information they need you ro provide (which will likely include sign-offs from your supervisor and/or others in management and/or the person or team responsible for network security).

Comment: That is why I'm running a separated database. It doesn't have real information on it, and to develop an application is necessary to test that it really works on the street. You can't code it entirely just to find that it needs completely redesigned to actually work outside of the company.

Comment: By the way, you are not answering anything useful. I asking how should I communicate with the IT, what information should I give, and what I need to ask. If it conforms to the company policy is off topic, and not something to be argued here. It is obvious that I will check this with the IT, because I'm preparing to it. I'm the one who decide if the application is relevant and useful, and sign offs with supervisor and/or others are an internal administration issue of the company, off topic here, and doesn't has anything to do with the information needed to communicate with the IT department.

Comment: I'm asking this because I need to meet the IT, and if I do not go with all the relevant information, I will waste time, and will need another meeting.

Comment: @bewe nice job *looking* a gift horse in the mouth

Comment: WRT "you are not answering anything useful", see edited emphasis of "ask your IT department...". That really is the only useful response here IMO. If your company already uses such applications *IT will already know the technical requirements for publishing one* and what they will need from you is the "what" and the "why" (what the application is, and why it needs to be publically addressable at this time). Assuming it is a sizable company IT will have a document that lists what you need to provide them with (both technically and to conform to local policy) and a procedure for doing so.

Comment: @David Spillett as an aspie, I have some difficulty communicating with neurotypicals. I'm asking what type of technical information should I be prepared to give them, and what is the terminology used for "opening the application to Internet". I find nonsensical that after me asking how should I speak to the IT, you say that I should speak with the IT. I provided an example of a possible laundry list, and that's what I expected to be answered.